# Explanation of the meaning of those singlets, doublets

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, quantum-spin, group-theory

I am stuck in understanding and following the explanation (?) written within the red square bracket in the notes below.

Can someone please explain me what does this mean? I tried to search in other books too but I did not find anything. I'm stuck over here since hours.
Thank you!

[image]

Comment: You should write the question and equations directly. The image can break and it is very charged as it is.

Comment: Please don't post images in place of text and mathematical equations (2 years, 3 months user).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Abstractly, $\hat s_i$ are spin operators that act on general states $|s,s_z \rangle$ where the first and second labels refer to the total spin and spin-projection along an arbitrary axis respectively.

- "$s$" is the total spin and can be any half integer, $s=0,\frac{1}{2},1,\frac{3}{2},\ldots$.
- "$s_z$" can range from $-s$ to $+s$, with unit intervals $\Delta s_z=\pm 1$.

When the spin operator is written as $\hat s_i=\hbar \sigma_i$, where $\sigma_i$ are the standard two-dimensional Pauli matrices, one is implicitly assuming that we are acting on two-dimensional vectors. The notes appear to be addressing the following question: if our state space is two-dimensional, which vectors $|s,s_z\rangle$ span it? What linear combinations of $|s,s_z\rangle$ form an orthonormal basis?

It's a bit of a reverse-logic question, since the relation $\hat s_i=\hbar \sigma_i$ is originally derived for the spin-$1/2$ representation of $su(2)$, which tells you that $|\frac{1}{2},\pm\frac{1}{2}\rangle$ is by definition the basis, but I suppose someone could ask this question.

The author notices that, a two-dimensional state space could only be constructed out of two one-dimensional (spin-0) spin states, or one two-dimensional (spin-$1/2$) spin state. However the first possibility is wrong because $s^2|0,0\rangle=0$, but you have already showed that $s^2=\frac{3}{4}\hbar\hat 1$ with the Pauli matrices. So it must be the second possibility, that $|\frac{1}{2},\pm\frac{1}{2}\rangle$ is the valid basis.

Comment: Thank you so much!!